# Encryption technology for DARPA

Tags: cryptanalysis

I'm working on a short story taking place in the near future in which a hacker gains access to the DARPA mainframe and files related to a highly classified DARPA project.

Being ignorant about state of the art cryptanalysis techniques, is it safe to say it would be virtually impossible to decipher encrypted DARPA files unless our rogue programmer has access to a quantum computer?

Comment: I wouldn't say virtually impossible. I mean, where are the keys stored? How are the keys used? If keys are ever used on a machine that an attacker controls, the attacker can get them. If keys are stored and used on a separate machine, the attacker can attack that machine (even if it is air-gapped). If keys are stored in humans, don't forget [this method](https://xkcd.com/538/).

Comment: @mikeazo - That's a good question. What is standard procedure for storing the private keys if we assume DARPA is using RSA encryption? We'll assume no strong arm tactics are used to get the files.

Comment: I would assume [Common Access Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Access_Card) and software like [this](http://www.spi.dod.mil/ewizard.htm). For a setup like that, where the attacker has broken into some sort of storage server and users pull the files off the server, decrypt them to gain access, then wipe (so unencrypted versions are never on the server and the attacker only has access to the server), then an attackers options are very limited. Quantum computer would do the trick, so would stealing a CAC and PIN.

Comment: As the author, you have a great deal of flexibility; you could make it quite easy (for example, an admin used the same password as his Ashley Madison login), you could make it quite difficult (as requiring a Quantum Computer, if you need a technical term, try "Elliptic Curve"), or completely impossible.  Setting things up so that, without a QC, it'd be completely infeasible would be plausible.

Comment: The second challenge for the would-be hacker is covering up his tracks after he downloads copies of said files from the DARPA mainframe. But if he's already hacking in as the system admin, he'd be able to delete all evidence from the log files, right?

Comment: how about using some unknown vulnerability in the OS kernel which allows him to extract the encryption subkeys from memory that the mainframe uses, then he exports the encrypted data, and decrypts it offsite.